# Get event trigger while crash application

Tags: android, events, crash

I want to open static screen with Restart application option whenever application is crashing. It can from any of screen. Is it possible to trigger application crash event on application level and start new screen? I did not getting anything for this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Application class, you can add a UncaughtExceptionHandler.

For instance, add this variable to the application class:

```java
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler unCaughtExceptionHandler = (thread, ex) -> {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        [set some sharedpreference like `isCrash` to true]
};
```

The Application class itself has a method called

`setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)`

Now set the custom variable `unCaughtExceptionHandler` as the parameter for that method.

On the next boot of the app, just load the sharedPref `isCrash`. 
When this is true, show a 'oh no, the app crashed' screen and set the isCrash to false again.

When the `isCrash` is false, just load the usual activity

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or just open the crash intent right away when crashing

Comment: Thanks @Emiel I will try this.